# How to call overriden methods in base constructor

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

Here is my code.
It throws when creating new instance of inherited map (CustomMap).
It seems that the `init` function is not available in the base constructor call when calling `namespace.Map.apply(this, mapContainer);`

https://jsfiddle.net/y6qg4xbn/

```
var namespace = window.namespace || {};

namespace.Map = function (mapContainer) {

    this.mapContainer = mapContainer;

    this.preinit();
    this.init();
}

namespace.Map.prototype.preinit = function () {
};

namespace.Map.prototype.init = function () {
};

namespace.CustomMap = function (mapContainer) {
    namespace.Map.apply(this, mapContainer);
};
namespace.CustomMap.prototype = Object.create(namespace.Map);
namespace.CustomMap.prototype.preinit = function () {
    // do some stuff or even call base preinit
}

var newMap = new namespace.Map();
var inheritedMap = new namespace.CustomMap();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
namespace.CustomMap.prototype = Object.create(namespace.Map);
```

to this:

```
namespace.CustomMap.prototype = Object.create(namespace.Map.prototype);
```

You should base the `CustomMap.prototype` on the `Map.prototype`, not on `Map`.  There was no `.init()` method in the base because you didn't include the base prototype when creating the derived prototype.

---

And, there's a separate problem where you need to change this:

```
namespace.Map.apply(this, mapContainer);
```

to this:

```
namespace.Map.call(this, mapContainer);
```

because `mapContainer` is a specific variable, not an array of arguments which means you should use `.call()` instead of `.apply()`.